# Wrap HTML Tag around strings in HTML code

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm using PHP 7.3+. I want to wrap different HTML tags around each letter in my HTML code, but only around text, not other HTML tags. For example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is the first heading</h1>
  <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I basically want to wrap `<span class="customclass"></span>` around each **letter** of the website text. Which are:

```
This is the first heading
Some Paragraph
List item 1
List item 2
```

Here is the expected output:

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <h1><span class="customclass">T</span><span class="customclass">h</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span> <span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span> <span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">h</span><span class="customclass">e</span> <span class="customclass">f</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">r</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span> <span class="customclass">h</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">d</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">n</span><span class="customclass">g</span></h1>
  <p><span class="customclass">S</span><span class="customclass">o</span><span class="customclass">m</span><span class="customclass">e</span> <span class="customclass">P</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">r</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">g</span><span class="customclass">r</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">p</span><span class="customclass">h</span></p>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="customclass">L</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span> <span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">m</span> <span class="customclass">1</span></li>
    <li><span class="customclass">L</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span> <span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">m</span> <span class="customclass">2</span></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have got this regex, but it's only wrapping it around the 2 last words  and what I need is each letters:

```
preg_replace('/\b[\w\'-]+\W+\K.*\S/s', '<span class="customclass">$0</span>', $html);
```

How is this possible with PHP?

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: You want every *letter* on this page to be wrapped in that HTML?

Comment: @JohnConde Ah thanks for pointing out the regexes. Didn't know that. Every letter yes.

Comment: Is the structure of this data *always* going to be *exactly* like we see here?

Comment: @JohnConde No it will be different. They will be random HTML pages.

Comment: `This is the first heading` is a sentence (not being too pedantic here) and not a letter, a letter is 1 character such as `T`.

Comment: What do you mean by each letter? What is your expected output by giving the provided input?

Comment: @NigelRen I want every letter/character in that to be wrapped around.

Comment: @AliKhalili I just added the expected output to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code grabs the body of the HTML document and then recursively looks for elements and the text within those elements. If it find any, it wraps each letter in a span tag.

This supports custom tags and only affect the HTML in the `<body>` of the document.

```
$string ='<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is the first heading</h1>
  <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>';


$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

foreach ($body->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
    replaceText($element);
}

$html = html_entity_decode($dom->saveHTML());

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);

function replaceText(DOMNode $node) {
    if ($node instanceof DOMText) {
        $newString = '';
        foreach(str_split($node->nodeValue) as $char) {
            if (!trim($char)) {
                continue;
            }
            $newString .= sprintf('<span class="customclass">%s</span>', $char);
        }
        $node->nodeValue = $newString;
        return $node;
    }
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
            return replaceText($childNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <h1><span class="customclass">T</span><span class="customclass">h</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">h</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">f</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">r</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">h</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">d</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">n</span><span class="customclass">g</span></h1>
  <p><span class="customclass">S</span><span class="customclass">o</span><span class="customclass">m</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">P</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">r</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">g</span><span class="customclass">r</span><span class="customclass">a</span><span class="customclass">p</span><span class="customclass">h</span></p>
  <ul>
  <li><span class="customclass">L</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">m</span><span class="customclass">1</span></li>
    <li><span class="customclass">L</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">s</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">i</span><span class="customclass">t</span><span class="customclass">e</span><span class="customclass">m</span><span class="customclass">2</span></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```